# Building a presentation display for big screen using Silverlight

Tags: silverlight, slideshow, stackpanel, presentation

Our company wants to replace the powerpoint presentation (company info, etc) displayed on the big screen TV in the lobby with something more professional. I can do that easily using ASP.NET/HTML and JQuery (use JQuery to cycle through the DIVs), but I want to develop it in Silverlight - basically a web-based Silverlight application that fades in/out through the different "slides". It'll be tied to a SQL server database.

I'm new to Silverlight (my 1st project) and am not sure how to proceed (I'm pretty conversant with ASP.NET). I'm not sure which container (stackpanel, grid, canvas) to use in building the slides. I tried using stackpanels but couldn't get it to fade from one stackpanel to another.

Can someone please help me out??

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

My answer at "Animation target not specified issue - Silverlight storyboards." will do the trick at 
[Animation target not specified issue - Silverlight storyboards](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6663528/animation-target-not-specified-issue-silverlight-storyboards/6669118#6669118)

When placing your Dia in a Grid you can easy use the PlaneProjection to move it around animating the LocalOffsetX property of the PlaneProjection for example.

```
    <Grid>
        <Grid.Projection>
            <PlaneProjection />
        </Grid.Projection>
        <Dia />
    </Grid>
```

If you need more explanation, let me know. I will be happy to elaborate in more detail.
Please let me know if this helped you.

Comment: Thanks for the response, Magiel. I ended up doing it in regular ASP.NET/VB.NET due to time constraints.